# Sequelize - Search using the associated table but exclude results from the associated table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is it possible to search using the associated table but excluding the data in the associated table?

E.g.

```
db.Bill.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: self.db.Group,
        where: {
            id: groupId
        },
        include: [{
            model: self.db.Account,
            where: {username: username}
        }]
    }]
});
```

Currently, I get these results...

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title",
    "category": "OTHERS",
    "currency": "php",
    "recurring": false,
    "date_from": null,
    "date_to": null,
    "createdAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:08.000Z",
    "group_id": 2,
    "Group": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Group",
      "createdAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:07.000Z",
      "updatedAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:07.000Z",
      "Account": {
            "username": "username"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I want to find all the bills under a group but I only want the results to be

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Title",
    "category": "OTHERS",
    "currency": "php",
    "recurring": false,
    "date_from": null,
    "date_to": null,
    "createdAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:08.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2015-08-12T10:54:08.000Z",
    "group_id": 2
  }
];
```

Comment: Any reason not to `db.Group.findAll({include: [{model: self.db.Bill, where: {group_id: groupid}}]});`? or simply not include "Group" at all and just filter on `group_id: groupid`?

Comment: Hi Amit, yes I can do that but let's say I want to find by username also in the Account table associated to the Group table. (Edited the question)

Comment: you can do this using lodash - https://lodash.com/docs#omit - of course that's not going to stop the results from being produced, it'll just clean up the final product the way you want.

Comment: @akosidoctor26 - I'm not sure how far it would go, but even with your revised question it's possible to reverse the query such you'll *only* get the redundant part once, and the "real" requested data without sub-relations.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?